# cannot get the id of every row's last column in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have a table which is dynamically built, what i want is that when i click, a function executes that give me the id of last column of every row, I used the following code where i alert every columns's id but it is not working . can any one help me ???? this is the loop which is used in the function

```
$('table[id="' + tableID + '"]').find('tr').each(function () {
        alert($('td:last-child').attr("id"));

    });
```

what i get in the alert is the id of the first row's last column in every iteration of the loop

Comment: I'm nitpicking but if you are looking for an element by id there is no need to do $('table[id="mytableid"]'), all ids in a document is(should be) unique so there is no need to filter it first by table. Just do $('#mytableid'). It's also much faster http://jsperf.com/selectors-tag-or-not (not that you'd ever notice the difference in most cases..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative might be:

```
$('table#'+ tableID +' tr').each(function () {
    var lastCellOfCurrentRowId = $(this).find('td:last-child').attr("id");
});
```

The important thing is the $(this) inside the each iterator. It refers to current element on the iteration, for instance each row element (TR) on the table. From that element you can do whatever you need, for this case just find the last cell ID.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('table[id="' + tableID + '"] tr').each(function () {
    alert($('td:last-child').attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a context for the selector, so that you're looking for the last `<td>` inside the current row being looked at by the `.each()` function, so change it to:

```
alert($('td:last-child', this).attr("id"));
```

Comment: yes its working , but i didnot understand what is meant by context, in each iteration, context is automatically changed by the .each() , so why we need to explicitly mention it

Comment: @zeeshan When you're calling the jQuery function with a selector you're searching the document, unless you explicitly specify a context (a jQuery object or DOM element) to limit the search to. So while each iteration of `.each()` is its own context, it has no bearing on the call to the jQuery function, or the set of elements that it searches within.

Comment: @zeeshan Also, I'm curious (and a little confused) as to why you'd accept mine as the answer to the question, then reverse that and select instead an answer that is essentially identical and came seven minutes after mine.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a group of all the last TD's

```
$('#mytable tr td:last-child').each(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JgtV4/

As long as you only wanted to do this and not some more actions on each TR